# Validación con js para que el boton de editar ó actualizar se deshabilite si no hay cambios en los input del form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

me gustaría validar por ejemplo este input:

```
<div class="col">
                        <label for="">Destino</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="destino" id="idDestino" value="<?php echo $destino?>" >
                    </div>
```

lo que me gustaría que se logre es que a la hora de que no se realizen cambios dentro del input el boton se encuentre deshabilitado y cuando ya se modifique algo este se pueda habilitar nuevamente para actualizar el dato, se que esto se puede lograr con js. Ejemplo de mi button:

```
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Actualizar" name="actualizarProgramaCarga" onClick="validarModalEditarPrograma(evento) return confirm('¿Estas seguro/a de guardar los cambios?');">
```

Comment: y que has intentado en javascript???

Comment: algoasi deberia funcionarte: https://jsfiddle.net/2rztnhpu/

Comment: Mmmmm... ¿Acaso no te habían cerrado la misma pregunta hace unas horas?

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Hola, muy buenas tardes, ya he resuelto mi duda, muchas gracias

Comment: Si ya has resuelto el problema, entonces debes colocarlo como respuesta, y [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Por cierto, ya que estás ignorando varios comentarios en tus preguntas: ¡no los ignores! Otros usuarios intentan ayudarte a mejorar tus preguntas. Recuerda que las preguntas y sus respuestas deben ser útiles no solo para ti, sino también para otros que más adelante lleguen a tener inconvenientes similares.

Comment: @padaleiana hola, pido mil disculpas, soy nuevo aún en esta comundidad.